# differences between way & in a way

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering when to use "way" and when to use "in a way".

For example,

1: I told you we should have done it my way!

2: They grinned at her in a friendly way.

3: Do it in the right way.

4: Do it the teacher's way.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Examples #1, #2, and #4 sound natural to my (American) ear.

Example #3 should be "Do it right." or "Do it the right way."

"In a way" is essentially an adverbial phrase.  In example #2, it modifies "grinned at her".

"In a way" can also mean "kind of" or "sort of", which make a statement weaker or vaguer.  It can be used informally as a "complete" sentence replying to a suggestion.  When used as a reply, it is almost a dare to the other person to ask for more details.

"A way" is a path or method for doing something.  For example, "*The Way Forward.*"  It acts like a noun.

"<something> is in the way" means that "<something> is an obstacle".  My mental picture is of a person or a boulder blocking a narrow road.

Comment: why is it only *do it right way*, bot *do it in right way*?